# Why is "#{String}" a common idiom in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

A Ruby dev I know asked this; my answer is below... Are there other, better reasons?

Why do so many Ruby programmers do

```
"#{string}"
```

rather than

```
string
```

since the second form is simpler and more efficient?

Comment: I disagree with the premise of the question. In my experience if someone does that it's usually either a mistake (the string previously contained something else and he forgot to remove the quotes when he removed the something else) or the person in question simply does not understand strings in ruby.

Comment: maybe `"#{string}"`, not `"{string}"`, anyway it's not so common idiom

Comment: Can you clarify with a slightly more fleshed-out example or may be even a link to someplace you've seen this? If you mean somebody's writing things along the lines of `str = "#{"hello"}"`, I don't believe that's a remotely common idiom.

Comment: @sepp2k: The premise is that apparently the developer who asked this on twitter is seeing this a lot in the project he's working on...

Comment: @fl00r - yeah, that was the usage, as indicated in the question title.

Comment: I prefer the C-like variant: `"%s" % string` or if you use more than one replacement: `"%s %d" % [string, 1234]`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is this a common idiom for Ruby developers?  I don't see it that much.

Comment: Perhaps it's a common idiom among programmers coming from a specific background into ruby? I'm relaying a question here, so I'm perfectly comfortable with the "It isn't that common, and it's just as wrong as you're thinking it is" answer.

Comment: It's a common idiom among programmers who haven't thought about what they are doing. I've seen the same thing in Perl code too and it makes me nuts.

Answer (score 3):

Smaller changes when you later need to do more than simply get the value of the string, but also prepend/append to it at the point of use seems to be the best motivation I can find for that idiom.

Comment: It's a piss-poor motivation, mind you, but it's one I could hear a PHB pronouncing as a reason to do it.

Comment: LOL at PHB attempt to understand what makes programmers more efficient :)

Answer (score 3):

There is only one case where this is a recommended idiom :

```
fname = 'john'
lname  = 'doe' 
name = "#{fname} #{lname}"
```

The code above is more efficient than :

```
name = fname + ' ' + lname
```

or

```
name = [fname, lname].join(' ')
```

Comment: `name = "%s %s" % [fname, lname]`

Answer (score 2):

What's the broader context of some of the usages? The only thing I can come up with beyond what's already been mentioned is as a loose attempt at type safety; that is, you may receive anything as an argument, and this could ensure that whatever you pass in walks like a duck..or, well, a string (though `string.to_s` would arguably be clearer).

In general though, this is probably a code smell that someone along the way thought was Best Practices.

Answer (score 2):

I use this kind of code, so that I can pass `nil` as string and it still will work on a string, rather than seeing some exceptions flying:

```
def short(string = nil)
  "#{string}"[0..7]
end
```

And it's easier/faster to append some debug code, if it's already in quotes.

So in short: It's more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is easy way to convert any to string? Because it is the same as call `to_s` method. But it is quite strange way :).

```
a = [1,2,3]
"#{a}"
#=> "123"
a.to_s
#=> "123"
```

Comment: #{a} is 4 keystrokes.

a.to_s is 6 keystrokes

Saves 2 keystrokes. That'd be taking the definition of "easy" very literally though ;-).

Comment: Yep, It is just suggestion :) I am not fan of using topic "idiom"

Comment: Problem is that a.to_s in Ruby 1.9 doesn't do that.

Comment: @ScottD - it doesn't do it in Ruby 1.8, either, for that matter. At least, not for me.

Comment: In case of Array, it will return of course "123" (not "1,2,3").

Answer (score 0):

Interesting answers, everyone. I'm the developer who asked the original question. To give some more context, I see this occasionally at my current job, and also sometimes in sample code on the Rails list, with variables that are known in advance to contain strings. I could sort of understand it as a substitute for to_s, but I don't think that's what's going on here; I think people just forget that you don't need the interpolation syntax if you're just passing a string variable.

If anyone tried to tell me this was a best practice, I'd run away at top speed.

Answer (score 0):

I could image this being useful in cases where the object being interpolated is not always a String, as the interpolation implicitly calls `#to_s`:

```
"#{'bla'}"           => "bla"
"#{%r([a-z])}"       => "(?-mix:[a-z])"
"#{{:bla => :blub}}" => "blablub"
```

May make sense when logging something, where you don't care so much about the output format, but never want an error because of a wrong argument type.

Comment: gah, need to wake up more, didn't see the other comments pointing out the to_s...